# Cannot upload product image via woocommerce importer

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I am planning to upload product CSV to woocommerce. But in the current stage, after I add multiple image urls in the images column. The product image cannot update properly. Only the first url successfully uploaded. The rest cannot upload forever.

my csv file for images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVUG8.png)

Comment: Because the image is featured image - only one is allowed. The rest of the images should be uploaded to the product gallery.

Comment: But there is no product gallery exist in the woocommerce column. In fact the official documentation also state that should upload it in Images column with comma to seperate different image

Comment: Look here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-import-suite-column-header-reference/

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. This is due to the image is too big and woocommerce cannot autoupload it. After I reduce the size from 2mb to 200k. It works!